# How do I find all words in a string that lie between two markers?

Tags: php

I have a function that returns the first substring between two marker words:

```
$opmerking = "This is an @Example@ or not? @Example2@ hehe."; 
$tag = get_string_between($opmerking, '@', '@');

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
  $string = ' ' . $string;
  $ini = strpos($string, $start);
  if ($ini == 0) return '';
  $ini += strlen($start);
  $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
  return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

Now it returns the first word: `$tag = "Example"`.

But I want that it returns a array with *all* the words between `@` `@`.

Maybe a loop or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Just use a loop as you thought:

```
function get_string_between($string, $open, $close) {
  $matches = [];
  $begin = 0;
  while (false !== ($begin = strpos($string, $open, $begin))) {
    $begin += strlen($open);
    $end = strpos($string, $close, $begin);
    if (false !== $end) {
      $matches[] = substr($string, $begin, $end-$begin);
      $begin = $end + strlen($close);
    }
  }
  return $matches;
}
```

[Live example at 3v4l.](https://3v4l.org/P7cGW)

Note that, if you expect big strings and many matches, a generator might be better suited.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an offset, and change it each time you call the function.

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end, $offset){
  $string = ' ' . $string;
  $ini = strpos($string, $start, $offset);
  if ($ini == 0) return '';
  $ini += strlen($start);
  $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini, $offset) - $ini;
  return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```